# How to use single CA certificate to many puppet masters?

Tags: puppet

Here's what I performed:

**puppetmaster1**:

1. cleared ssl directory. sudo rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
2. stopped services. puppet resource service puppet ensure=stopped, puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=stopped
3. regenerate CA. puppetserver ca setup
4. new ca is generated and will be used to different puppet masters
5. run puppet & puppetserver service. puppet resource service puppet ensure=running, puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
6. Downloaded .pem files using sftp. (/ssl/certs/ca.pem, /ssl/certs/puppetmaster1.local.pem, /ssl/crl.pem, /ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem, /ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem)
7. Downloaded .pem files will be uploaded to different puppet masters to use the same CA

**puppetmaster2**:

1. cleared ssl directory. sudo rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
2. stopped services. puppet resource service puppet ensure=stopped, puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=stopped
3. regenerate CA. puppetserver ca setup
4. run puppet & puppetserver service. puppet resource service puppet ensure=running, puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
5. Upload .pem files from puppetmaster1 using sftp.
6. Overwrite .pem files from .pem files of puppetmaster1 (/ssl/certs/ca.pem, /ssl/certs/puppetmaster1.local.pem, /ssl/crl.pem, /ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem, /ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem)

Error is showing:
[image: certificate verify failed]

Comment: Are you really sure you want to share the cert? Won't the cert's common name be wrong for puppetmaster2, leading to problem with clients rejecting the cert because its common name doesn't match the server name? I'd suggest sharing the CA and generating separate certs for the two servers. If they will both be masquerading using a shared alias, you can add subject alternate names to the certs.

Comment: You should not share a CA cert among masters.  You should share a whole CA, which owns and exclusively controls its cert.  That can be a function of a designated one of your masters, or it can be a separate machine.

Comment: Hi @Jon thanks for the response. You're correct I'm having that error but I don't know how to setup your suggestion. Do you have any guide how to make that setup sharing the CA to different servers? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, thanks for the response. Do you have a guide how to setup that kind of approach? Thanks!